# About the definition on cohomology of groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

I'm studying again cohomology of groups from Brown's book and other books and notes. I want to write some proof of well known statements but I have trouble with this one:

Let be $G$ a group and $M$ a left $G-$module. In order to define the cohomology groups $H^{n}(G,M)$: for $n\geq 0$ let $C^{n}(G,M)$ be the set of all functions from $G^{n}$ to $M$. The coboundary homomorphisms are defined by

$$\delta^{n+1}: C^{n}(G,M)\longrightarrow C^{n+1}(G,M)$$

$$\delta^{n+1}(\phi)(g_{1},...,g_{n+1})=g_{1}\phi(g_{2},...,g_{n})+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i}\phi(g_{1},...,g_{i}g_{i+1},...,g_{n+1})+(-1)^{n+1}\phi(g_{1},...,g_{n})$$

I want to proof that :

$$\delta^{n+1}\circ \delta^{n}=0$$

My Aproach: Let be $C_{n}(G)=G^{n+1}$ and then define $d_{n}:C_{n}\longrightarrow C_{n-1}$ by:

$$d_{n}(g_{1},...,g_{n+1})=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}(g_{1},...,g_{i-1},g_{i+1},...,g_{n})$$

It is well known that :

$$d_{n}\circ d_{n+1}=0$$

Now apply the functor $F=Hom_{G}(\cdot, M)$ to the complex  $C_{n}(G)$ and get the result. Is this a proof?

Can be the equation $\delta^{n+1}\circ\delta^{n}=0$ be proved in another way?

Comment: It might be soothing to know that this construction (supposedly a "definition") is just an _example_ of a computation of a derived functor via a specific injective resolution. One can prove that the resulting cohomology does not depend on the choice of resolution. Whew. :) Yes, there is a tradition to avoid talking in such terms, but it had always been vaguely disturbing to me. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett so...how can be proof the equation?

Comment: Well, your "it is well-known that $d\circ d=0$ is the main point... That is, we can ask, in a naive setting, "why is $d\cric d=0$? Of course, this depends on definitions/characterizations...

Comment: The $d_n$ are missing signs. Also you should specify the $G$-action. That $d\circ d=0$ is more or less the same proof as for singular or cellular homology. In fact, the complex you give can be obtained as a cellular complex of a CW-complex.

Comment: I'm sorry. INow I put the $(-1)^{i}$ factor.